# How to install Evernote android-job on React Native?

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-support-library, dex

---

I've created a repo in which the error can be easily reproducible:
https://github.com/yaronlevi/android_job_with_react_native

---

I am trying to install Evernote's library [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) for scheduling jobs in a React Native project (with Play Services also installed).

When I run the project I get an error in the Dex phase:

**Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BundleUtil**

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BundleUtil;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BundleUtil;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

It seems like several libraries are trying to fetch different versions of a support library.

What I did is just added [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) to the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.2'
}
```

The exact steps I took can be seen in the repo link above. (You can clone it and run easily).

How can I solve the conflict that occurs regarding the support library.

Thanks in advance (-:

Comment: For the record, the same question has been posted [on project's Github](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/issues/365) and got a response from the library author.

Comment: I posted that question (-: